# C# reflection: providing T for a generic method

Tags: c#, generics, reflection, compiler-errors

I'm not experienced using reflection and generic methods, here are two methods. I think you can understand the thing I'm trying to do.

```
public static T GetInHeaderProperty<T>() where T : new()
{
    dynamic result = new T();

    result.CompanyId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CompanyId"];
    result.UserId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UserId"];
    result.Password = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Password"];
    result.MessageId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MessageId"];

    Type platformType = typeof(T).GetProperty("PlatformType").PropertyType;
    // Here is my problem, I can not compile my code because of this line
    result.PlatformType = (dynamic)GetPlatformType<platformType>();
    //-------------------------------------------------------------------

    return (T)result;
}

public static T GetPlatformType<T>() where T : struct
{
    string platform = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Platform"];
    T value;
    if (Enum.TryParse(platform, out value))
        return value;
    else
        return default(T);
}
```

I'm getting the following error at compile time:

> The type or namespace name 'platformType' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?).

How can I call this method?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you dont know the type until runtime, you probably dont need/want generics.

Comment: Maybe you should adjust your question a bit to help others which have the same problem. Your selected anwer is not wrong but just matches to your code not to the general question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GetPlatformType is a generic method, but instead of passing it a generic parameter, you're passing it a Type object that describes the type. A generic parameter T must be known during compile time, not passed in runtime.

You can use the Enum.Parse overload, passing it the Type object, but you'll have to wrap it in a try/catch block yourself (no TryParse overload).

Comment: Enum.Parse returns object. How can I cast the returning object to the type I work with?

Answer (score 2):

Try using [MakeGenericMethod](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodinfo.makegenericmethod.aspx).

You need to get the [MethodInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodinfo.aspx) for the method first. Maybe there is a better way with using some dynamic stuff but this is the way i usually go. Finally you need to call [Invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a89hcwhh.aspx).